# Build Git Subtree with DockerFile

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile, gradlew

I have a project with DockerFile at the root. The project contain subtree folder2 which itself is a gradle project. I want to cd into folder2 build the gradle project and copy build files to root folder. I have tried following

```
WORKDIR "/folder2"   
COPY ./folder2 /folder2

RUN ./gradlew build
```

but i receive this error "gradlew not found". Any guidance would be appreciated. The project structure is

```
folder1
     DockerFile
     folder2
        gradlew 
        other files
```

Comment: Did you `COPY` the content into the image first?  Can you provide a more complete (running) extract of the Dockerfile?

Comment: Hey, yes I have added `COPY` now and it seems to work but then i am getting this error
`Failed to create parent directory '/folder2/.gradle' when creating directory '/folder2/.gradle/6.6.1/fileHashes' `